# Add custom part name to header using kaobook template in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, kaobook

I am using the kaobook template for my document in LaTeX, and I would like to add the custom part name to the header. By default, the header only shows the chapter name. How can I modify the kaobook template to include the part name in the header, and how can I update it when using the `\addpart` command ?

Answer (score 0):

The definitions that you need to tweek are in the kaorefs.sty
Inside this file there is a list that you can edit with custom part names.

```
    \addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\chapternameshort}{Chap.}
  \renewcommand{\sectionname}{Section}
  \renewcommand{\sectionnameshort}{Sec.}
  \renewcommand{\subsectionname}{Subsection}
  \renewcommand{\subsectionnameplural}{Subsections}
  \renewcommand{\subsectionnameshort}{Subsec.}
  \renewcommand{\figurenameshort}{Fig.}
  \renewcommand{\tablenameshort}{Tab.}
  \renewcommand{\eqname}{Equation}
  \renewcommand{\eqnameshort}{Eq.}
  \renewcommand{\defname}{Definition}
  \renewcommand{\assumname}{Assumption}
  \renewcommand{\thmname}{Theorem}
  \renewcommand{\propname}{Proposition}
  \renewcommand{\lemmaname}{Lemma}
  \renewcommand{\remarkname}{Remark}
  \renewcommand{\examplename}{Example}
  \renewcommand{\exercisename}{Exercise}
}
```

Then you can edit the Headers and Footers section in kao.sty

Comment: Please explain better, for example showing some TeX code ...

Comment: I think it is better now.